# How to search for a specific filename in the sdcard by android ContentResolver.query using selection and selectionArgs?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I have retrieved a uri to sdcard via DocumentsContract.BuildDocumentUriUsingTree and now I am trying to look for a file in a directory which contains many files. I have tried the following code snippet:

```
selection = "_display_name='111'"; //I haven't use selectionArgs here for simplicity 
context.contentResolver.query(childrenUri, projection, selection, null, null)
```

I have also tried "_display_name=?" and use selectionArgs but it looks the provider completely ignore my selection and always returns all files in the directory.

I have tested it with Samsung S7 - Android 8.
How can I tell the query to just look for specific filename?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the provider you're using is `androidx.core.content.FileProvider` (according to what you've declared in your manifest), the `selection`, `selectionArgs` and `sortOrder` parameters of `FileProvider.query` are... *not* used at all in AndroidX's implementation !

See the v1.2.0 source [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-support-lib-19.1.0/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.java) (line 409)

The only solution I found is to filter and sort the results *post-query, in your own code*. 
And yeah, that's kinda sad...